# How to speed up python networking?

Tags: python, performance, sockets, python-2.7, network-programming

I am finding python networking *slow*.

I have a server (written in C). I tested it with my client (python).
I could reach `2MB/s`. It worried me so I checked this:

host1 (client):
`cat some_big_file | nc host2 9999`

host2 (server):
`nc -l 0.0.0.0 9999 | pv > /dev/null`

I reached something around 120MB/s (1Gb).

The server is not a bottleneck, we use it on production and it can handle more. But to be sure I copied simple python `gevent` server for tests. It looks like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  from gevent.server import StreamServer
  from gevent.pool import Pool

  def handle(socket, address):
       while True:
           print socket.recv(1024)

  pool = Pool(20000)
  server = StreamServer(('0.0.0.0', 9999), handle, spawn=pool)
  server.serve_forever()
```

Next measure is to send from `nc (host1)` to `gserver (host2)`.

host1: `cat some_big_file | nc host2 9999`
host2: `./gserver.py | pv  > /dev/null`

The output on `host2`: `[ 101MB/s]`. Not bad.

But still, when I use my python client, it's slow. I switched client to `gevent` .I've tried with several greenlets. 1, 10, 100, 1000 - it didn't help too much, I could reach `20MB/s` with one python process or `~30MB/s` for 2, 3, 4, 5 separate python processes, it's something, but still not so good). Still slow. I've rewritten the client to be dumb, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import socket

c = socket.create_connection((sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
while 1:
        c.send('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n')
```

With this approach I could reach `10MB/s`. I also tried the approach with reading the whole big `2GB` file to memory and send it, similar result.

I also tried to run python scripts as separate processes (using `tmux`). If I used 1 process I could reach `10MB/s`, 2 processes `20MB/s`, 3 prcesses `23MB/s`, 4, 5, 6 processes didn't change anything (tested with `gevent` version and simple one).

Details:
Python-2.7.3
Debian 7 - standard installation
Machines are AWS instances, client is c1.medium and server is c3.xlarge.
nc and iperf measured 1Gb/s between machines.

Questions:

1. Why can I receive *a lot of data quickly* using python server (gevent server) but cannot send with the same speed even if C program can.
2. Why does doubling the processes not increase sending speed to the limit, only to some value.
3. Is there any way to send data fast in python using sockets?

Comment: `"I am finding python networking slow"`. No, you're finding *your application* (which happens to be written in Python) slow.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes, you're right... but I've tried different approaches hence that shortcut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not really that networking is slow - python function calls have a lot of overhead. If you call `connection.send` a lot of times, you're going to have a lot of wasted CPU time on function calls.

On my computer, your program averages about 35 MB/s. Doing a simple modification, I get 450 MB/s:

```
#...
c.send('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'*10+'\n')
```

I could reach speeds over 1GB/s, by sending even more data at once.

If you want to maximize your throughput, you should send as much data as possible in a single call to `send`. A simple way of doing it would be concatenating several strings before sending the final result. If you do this, remember python strings are immutable, so successive string concatenation (with large strings) is slow. You'll want to use a `bytearray` instead.

Comment: Even if you try to send few bytes worth of stuff at a time in C (or even assembly), it would still be slow, because *syscall* overhead would seriously limit how fast you can pass data to kernel.

Comment: @goncalopp, thanks for good explanation and for bytearray tip.

Comment: Another point is `Buffer Size` , RTL8168 has 8/16KB on-chip memory(Like L1,L2,L3 cache), never send a packet over  `Ethernet chips Internal Buff Size`.  Ethernet chips using  DMA so not free whole built-in memory. My opinion max size is `1600 byte`, `Data Interrupt` is hard, need  be careful set on your communication data pattern.  I reached 40microsecond (send+receive) packet time and use 2 converter(FIBER to CAT6A). Buffer size is important cos all chip got more ns(nanosecond) setup time, maybe small packet faster but your chip got more latency on send+receiving.  Cont.. >>

Comment: Cont.. >> You using big_packet you need fast_RAM + Big_CPU_Cache + Stable_CPU + Stable_Bridge_CPU(Like this: low FSB good for you, need convert every step clock set to bus level) . This is not only python or data pattern issue , include all points of your system(hardware, software, cables, etc.)

Comment: maybe nagle algorithm is the issue? (https://www.programmersought.com/article/96935148609/) when it enabled, it collects the data in the buffer and fire it when buffer is good enough for sending. When I developed tcp proxy on python, it was the source of the problem. Try, maybe it will help